# OpenCV Windows setup with CLion

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, cygwin, clion

I want to setup OpenCV on windows for the CLion IDE. I tried with OpenCV 3.1 and 2.4 with the same result. I have Windows 10 64 bits. CLion is using the cygwin environement.

What I did so far: 

1. Downloaded the exe from OpenCV and runned it (it extracted a package). My path is E:/opencv

2. Added OpenCV_DIR variable and added it to path 

3. Added this to my project CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(OpenCV_LIB_PATH E:/opencv/build/x64/vc12/lib)
set(OpenCV_LIB_DIR E:/opencv/build/x64/vc12/lib)
set(OpenCV_LIBS E:/opencv/build/x64/vc12/lib)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH E:/opencv/build)
set(OpenCV_DIR E:/opencv/build/x64/vc12)
include_directories(E:/opencv/build/include)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(good ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

I managed to use the OpenCV Mat in my program (The libraries are visible) but I receive an error when trying to open an image.


My program is: (just an example)

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    string imageName("../data/test.png");
    if( argc > 1)
    {
        imageName = argv[1];
    }
    Mat image;
    image = imread(imageName.c_str(), IMREAD_COLOR);
    if( image.empty() )
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Display window", image );
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is: When i run the project i get the error:

```
/cygdrive/d/projects/good/src/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
/cygdrive/d/projects/good/src/main.cpp:17:(.text+0xc4): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
/cygdrive/d/projects/good/src/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
/cygdrive/d/projects/good/src/main.cpp:23:(.text+0x177): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
/cygdrive/d/projects/good/src/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
/cygdrive/d/projects/good/src/main.cpp:24:(.text+0x1a8): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
/cygdrive/d/projects/good/src/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/cygdrive/d/projects/good/src/main.cpp:24:(.text+0x1ed): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/cygdrive/d/projects/good/src/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/cygdrive/d/projects/good/src/main.cpp:25:(.text+0x215): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cv::waitKey(int)'
CMakeFiles/good.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
E:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:278: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
E:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:278:(.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev]+0x36): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cv::fastFree(void*)'
CMakeFiles/good.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)':
E:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:298: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
E:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:298:(.text$_ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_[_ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_]+0x110): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
CMakeFiles/good.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
E:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:367: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
E:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:367:(.text$_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x44): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to link your app with the opencv libraries... Use the [TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) command for that.

Comment: i added target_link_libraries(PROJECT_NAME ${OpenCV_LIBS} ) with no result

Comment: Can you, please, post you complete `CMakeLists.txt`, this looks odd. (You really named your target **"PROJECT_NAME** ?)

Comment: No, i did not i edited the CMakeLists.txt, my project name is good.

Comment: Hmm, thinking about this more, it seems you're using the libraries built with MSVC, but building your app with the cygwin gcc. Are you sure this can be done? I don't have any experience with this particular setup, but based on a quick search it doesn't seem it will work. I suspect you will need to build OpenCV yourself, and use that.

Comment: I have also the same problem a yours and I am trying to solve it. I will also try to compile it with CMake for Cygwin I think some people on youtube did this. I will try this step